# What are all the officially published spells that let a character choose to fail their saving throw against the spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw

What are all the spells in any officially published sourcebook for 5e where a target is granted the option to deliberately fail their saving throw?

Comment: Is this just more of an "out of curiosity" question with no real unifying purpose?

Comment: @Medix2 Yes. There were a few spells on this list I didn't expect to be there; and a few I expected to be there that weren't. So I figured it would be good to post it here.

Comment: Voting to close, this is a list question for the sake of a list not solving an actual issue.

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith Lists that have specific criteria and don't result in practically-infinite, extremely subjective answers [aren't considered to meet the criteria we consider for "List Questions"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6444/42386), and generally do not need to be closed.

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith This is also argued here where, in the same breath that List Questions are confirmed to be off-topic, it's also specified that [short discrete lists don't count as "List Questions"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/181/42386).

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith We've done other bounded list questions. You don't have to like them (can downvote), but this seems bounded enough to answer.

Comment: @Xirema: Wouldn't it be easier to ask directly "Why such and such does not grant such option, while this and that does?"

Comment: @ZwiQ I think that would constitute a Designer Intent question, which is generally considered off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 8):

## These are all the published spells (as of August 2019)

- **Bones of the Earth** *(XGE, 150)*: A creature can choose to be lifted by a pillar of earth, instead of resisting it
- **Calm Emotions** *(PHB, 221)*: A creature can choose to have their emotions calmed (Charm/Fear effect suppressed, hostility suppressed) instead of resisting it
- **Scrying**: *(PHB, 273)*: A creature can choose to fail the saving throw if they want the caster to scry on them, and are aware the spell is being cast
- **Watery Sphere** *(XGE, 170)*: A creature can choose to be restrained by the sphere

## These spells allow a creature to be willingly affected without a saving throw (only unwilling targets must make the save)

The main difference is that with the prior list, the creature still makes the saving throw, but chooses to fail it. For this list, if the creature is willing, then they do not make a saving throw at all. This can be relevant for other effects which may or may not affect a creature's ability to pass or fail a saving throw.

- **Enlarge/Reduce** *(PHB, 237)*: A creature can willingly be targeted by the spell to be enlarged or shrunk
- **Levitate** *(PHB, 255)*: A creature can willingly be targeted by the spell to rise into the air
- **Mass Polymorph** *(XGE, 160)*: A creature can be willingly transformed into a different creature
- **Plane Shift** *(PHB, 266)*: The spell assumes target creatures are willing, but has stipulations for the situation where a creature is unwilling
- **Polymorph** *(PHB, 266)*: A creature can be willingly transformed into a different creature
- **Seeming**: *(PHB, 274)*: A creature can willingly have their clothes' appearance altered
- **True Polymorph** *(PHB, 283)*: A creature can be willingly transformed into a different creature (or object)

Comment: Some of these have a caveat that the targets must know the spell is being cast on it. I don't know if the intent of the question is just 'possibility of choice', but you may want to clarify not just which spells, but when (because they don't *always* get to choose in some of these cases.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you have the 2nd list. Those spells simply dont qualify under the criteria in your question.

Comment: @NautArch Colloquially, people are likely to lump them together, because in many (but not all!) circumstances, those spells are mechanically identical to the first list.

Comment: Except they don't explicitly state permission to fail. It's your question, but if you want those lumped in, i thin you should change your wording accordingly.